# Best practice to implement back functionality in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml

I'm not using deep linking, so all the pages/states appear as http://site.com

Is it still possible to implement back functionality in this case? It looks like flex has a browser history feature, but not sure if it would still work given that all the pages are at site.com

The other option is that I would save information in the main file itself so I can go to the last page and retrieve whatever data was on it.

Anyone can advise what's generally the best practice way to handle back functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know of any other way to implement browser history (ie, back/forward) without using deep linking (eg, `example.com/#foo`). This is how the Flex browser history components implement it.

However, one thing you *could* do, if you need to keep the URL static, is stick your Flex application in a frame. That way the outter frame would still show `example.com` while the inner frame is at, for example, `example.com/#widget=42`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Flex docs on [Deep Linking](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cb6.html) and the [Browser Manager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64e50-7ff4.html).

Comment: +1 @James Ward. He is an Evangelist for Flex. If he says to check out those documents ... I think you should, you would get a better grasp of what you can and cannot do e.g. The difference between the `HistoryManager` and the `BrowserManager`

Answer (score 1):

The best practice and generally the only way to do it is to use deep linking.

it's best because the users can add a section of your application to "Favorites" and that's an important feature to have IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Do you **need** to keep your website with just http:// site.com or is that just how it looks now because deep linking is not implemented?
Checkout [Angela's Accessible Rich Internet Application](http://www.accessiblerichinternetapplication.com/index.php/Development/Implementing-Deep-Linking-With-UrlKit) tutorial which gives instructions on how to quickly and easily set up deep linking using UrlKit. The added bonus of this site is that the tutorial is delivered in the environment described... IE: you can view the source for an "in production" example of the implementation.